# Protobuf import doesn't work, I've used the proto_path

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Here's my directory structure:

```
protobuf
├── commons.proto
└── operations.proto
```

Code in operations.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "commons.proto";

option java_multiple_files = true;
package tw.waterballsa.protobuf.operations;

message PlayerEnterSceneOperation {
  PlayerAppearance appearance = 1;
}
```

Code in commons.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package tw.waterballsa.protobuf.commons;

message PlayerAppearance {
  int32 hair = 1;
  int32 skin = 2;
  int32 eyes = 3;
  int32 nose = 4;
  int32 mouth = 5;
  int32 shirt = 6;
  int32 pants = 7;
  int32 shoes = 8;
}
```

My compile command: `protoc --proto_path=protobuf --java_out=<...> protobuf/operations.proto`

The result (error message):

```
operations.proto:8:3: "PlayerAppearance" is not defined.
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's confusing.

Here's the solution.

Represent your files using the following structure to correctly repreresent your `proto_buf` root (`protobuf`) and your protobuf sources `packages` name (`tw.waterballsa.protobuf.[commons|operations]`) converted to a folder strucutre.

```
.
└── protobuf
    └── tw
        └── waterballsa
            └── protobuf
                ├── commons
                │   └── commons.proto
                └── operations
                    └── operations.proto
```

In `operations.proto`, you *must* preserve the `package` reference in the fully qualified name for `PlayerAppearance`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package tw.waterballsa.protobuf.operations;

// Fully-qualified path to 'commons.proto'
import "tw/waterballsa/protobuf/commons/commons.proto";

option java_multiple_files = true;

message PlayerEnterSceneOperation {
  // Fully-qualified path to `PlayerAppearance'
  tw.waterballsa.protobuf.commons.PlayerAppearance appearance = 1;
}
```

And then:

```bash
PROTO_PATH_1="${PWD}/protobuf"

protoc \
--proto_path=${PROTO_PATH_1} \
--java_out=. \
${PROTO_PATH_1}/tw/waterballsa/protobuf/operations/operations.proto \
${PROTO_PATH_1}/tw/waterballsa/protobuf/commons/commons.proto
```

> **NOTE** Formally, every protobuf source (`*.proto`) should be prefixed by one of the `proto_path` path values. I'm using `PROTO_PATH_1` here to make this clear.

There are two important paths.

The first is the `package` paths.

When you define `proto_path`, you specify the root (host) folder that represents the hierarchy of protobuf package references.

In this case, there's a single `proto_path` root folder `${PWD}/protobuf`.

The second is the output|generated|host paths. These are often similar too but need not be identical to the protobuf `package` references.

The above `protoc` (which compiles `commons.proto` too) yields:

```
.
├── protobuf
│   └── tw
│       └── waterballsa
│           └── protobuf
│               ├── commons
│               │   └── commons.proto
│               └── operations
│                   └── operations.proto
├── README.md
└── tw
    └── waterballsa
        └── protobuf
            ├── commons
            │   └── Commons.java
            └── operations
                ├── Operations.java
                ├── PlayerEnterSceneOperation.java
                └── PlayerEnterSceneOperationOrBuilder.java
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. A Fully-qualified path works.
use tw.waterballsa.protobuf.commons.PlayerAppearance, instead of PlayerAppearance